# occur error when i want to consume web service with SOAP

Tags: objective-c, xcode, web-services, soap, ios4

I make a web service(`SampleService.asmx`) and put a method in it (`GetAllUserInfo2`) that return string. I test it on `Visual Studio` and work properly.

i use below message for consume it and i check Log file but occur error

```
//Message
NSString *soapMessage=@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
     "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
     "<soap:Body>\n"
     "<GetCategory xmlns=\"http://jahanmir.ir/\" />\n"
     "</soap:Body>\n"
     "</soap:Envelope>";

    NSURL *tmpURl=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.jahanmir.ir/SampleService.asmx"]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:tmpURl];
    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    //[theRequest addValue:@"http://jahanmir.ir/GetAllUserInfo2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest addValue:@"http://jahanmir.ir/SampleService.asmx?op=GetAllUserInfo2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    NSString *msgLength=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[soapMessage length]];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if(con)
        webData=[[NSMutableData data] retain];//webData is `NSMutableData`
```

---

```
//Log
2012-10-22 17:39:50.533 WebServices[522:f803] data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction: http://jahanmir.ir/SampleService.asmx?op=GetAllUserInfo2.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is in this line `[theRequest addValue:@"http://jahanmir.ir/GetAllUserInfo2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];`

You are making the Service request to the root not the asmx file.  This isn't tested but I think you would want to ad the header for `http://jahanmir.ir/SampleService.asmx?op=GetAllUserInfo2`

Comment: `[theRequest addValue:@"http://jahanmir.ir/SampleService.asmx?op=GetAllUserInfo2" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];`  See is that gives you a different error, but that URL goes directly to your service.

Comment: try changing the URL to `http://jahanmir.ir/SampleService.asmx` again i'm guessing but it looks like your service isn't correctly connecting to the method of the service.